# What is "unbounded dynamic polymorphism" in Smalltalk

Tags: polymorphism, smalltalk

What is "unbounded dynamic polymorphism" in Smalltalk? Could someone provide an example?

It's mentioned in this [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=yQU-NlmQb_UC&pg=PA238):*C++ templates: the complete guide*, p. 238.

Comment: I think Stephan's answer is right on the spot. As a side note, c++ book is very rarely a good source of information about Smalltalk. Some would be tempted to say about OOP as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[See](http://codeidol.com/cpp/cpp-templates/The-Polymorphic-Power-of-Templates/Dynamic-versus-Static-Polymorphism/)
In c++:
Polymorphism implemented via inheritance is bounded and dynamic:

- Bounded means that the interfaces of the types participating in the polymorphic behavior are predetermined by the design of the common base class (other terms for this concept are invasive or intrusive).
- Dynamic means that the binding of the interfaces is done at run time (dynamically).

Polymorphism implemented via templates is unbounded and static:

- Unbounded means that the interfaces of the types participating in the polymorphic behavior are not predetermined (other terms for this concept are noninvasive or nonintrusive).
- Static means that the binding of the interfaces is done at compile time (statically).

In Smalltalk, an object can decide if and how it wants to react to a message being sent at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the method you call on an object is decided at compile time. For a non-virtual method this is a straightforward, for a virtual call it's done via a vtable lookup. However, the key thing with the virtual call (which is where they polymorphism) comes in, is that the compiler has decided that it's valid to call the method and it knows which entry in the vtable to use. In

In Smalltalk the call is resolved at runtime. The type of the object being called against can vary between invocations and therefore the correct method (which may have been overridden) cannot be bound at compile time (the unbound bit) and must be resolved (the dynamic bit) at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`unbounded dynamic polymorphism` is not a language specific feature. So I am assuming that your question

> What is "unbounded dynamic polymorphism" in Smalltalk?

Can be simplify to

> What is "unbounded dynamic polymorphism"?

Which is explain in the documentation you've mention.
I guess you are asking what make smalltalk a unbounded dynamic polymorphic language?
First of all I am not giving credit to the term bound vs. unbound. The definition is not clear to me.

For example suppose I have a template class A, if you choose to instantiate it as a `A<int>` it is bound, there is no undeterministic things here. Even for the class A the interface is predetermined. What I would say is that template is a way of having polymorphic type in the same sense of Haskell type system.

I think the use of the term unbound/bound result of a poor definition of what is polymorphism. Polymorphism can apply to type or interface.

A polymorphic interface is a interface that can be implement choosing different behavior. For example object `a`, `b`, `c` can all respond in a different way to a `Copy` interface.

A polymorphic type is a type that have parameter.

As you can see polymorphic interface and polymorphic type are 2 things unrelated.

In other to classify C++ and smalltalk I would say the C++ is a statically type language with polymorphic type. And smalltalk is a dynamically type language. And it does not need polymorphic typing system because polymorphic type are only sensible in statically type language.